# Редиректы с 404 страниц на codeigniter?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, codeigniter

Интеерсует как реализовать функционал редиректов на codeigniter

проиндексирована гуглом у меня некая https://domain.com/example-page которой нету, она возвращает 404
так вот, по-нормальному я хочу посылать пользователя на какую-то другую рабочую страницу, как это сделать используя codeigniter?

Comment: "По нормальному" - это нормально оформить 404ю страницу. а не редиректить с неё.

Comment: Если страница переехала - можно редиректнуть на новую рабочую